# gradient tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

What is function of small slideballs (diamonds on the left side) in gradient tool of adobe illustrator?

[image]

I understand that the perpendicular slide bars (which are also removable from gradient slide bar tool) signify the gradual shifting of color concentration from one color to another. But I am unsure about the use of slideballs on the left side which resides just on the opposite portion.

Comment: sure, Have a look

Comment: Which ones are the "sideballs" the little diamonds on the left side of that line?

Comment: yes , I am asking about that only

Answer (score 2):

Those little diamonds are sliders to choose which color should be more dominant between the two colors. (Slide it to choose.) By default it is 50% (equal strength)

[image]

Notice how as I drag it towards a color, it becomes "weaker".

---

You can add other colors to a gradient, it'd probably be easier to use the *Gradient Panel* (**Window → Gradient** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

[image]

Just drag and drop a color into the gradient to add it:

[image]

Comment: can we use more than two color using gradient tool?

Comment: @RitwikBhattacharyya yes, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Welz is dead-on about the gradient panel.

Referring strictly to the **Gradient Annotator** which appears on gradient-filled objects on the artboard when you hover over them with the **Gradient Tool**..... Each "bit" has a different function. Some are similar to the panel functions, some are additional or different...

[image]

- **Black Circle** on the left - click-drag to reposition/move the gradient.
- **Black Diamond** on the right - click-drag to change the *length* of the gradient or *hover the cursor* just outside the diamond and you can *rotate* the gradient (you'll see the cursor change to the "rotate" cursor, then click-drag). The center of rotation is the *black circle* on the left.
- **White Squares** are "mix" points. You can use these to alter how two  color stops react to one another, allowing one color to extend closer to another. By default, these squares are placed at the 50% point between two color stops.
- **Color Pointed Squares** control the *color and opacity* of that stop point.

You can **double-click** a color stop to alter the color of that stop. Or merely **click** the bottom edge of the gradient "bar" to add a new color stop at the click location.